# Asymptotic Limit and Big O

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification, logarithms, asymptotics

Consider the asymptotic equality for $0<r<1$ $$I(r)\sim 
 \mathcal{O}    \left(\log{(1-\sqrt{1-r^2})}\right)\tag{1}$$ as $r\to 1^-$ and
where $\mathcal{O}$ denotes Big-O notation.

**Question:** Prove that $\lim_{r\to 1^-}I(r)=0$

My try: Assume on the contrary that $\lim_{r\to 1^-}I(r)\neq 0$ then we have from equation $(1)$,

$$
 \mathcal{O}    \left(\log{(1-\sqrt{1-r^2})}\right)\sim I(r)\tag{2}$$
So we get $$\lim_{r\to 1^-}  \frac{ \mathcal{O}    \left(\log{(1-\sqrt{1-r^2})}\right)  }{I(r)}=1$$ now since $\lim_{r\to 1^-}I(r)\neq 0$, so we get
$$\lim_{r\to 1^-}  \mathcal{O}    \left(\log{(1-\sqrt{1-r^2})}\right)=\lim_{r\to 1^-} I(r)$$
So we get $$  \lim_{r\to 1^-} I(r)=\mathcal{O}(0)   $$
So we get $$  \lim_{r\to 1^-} I(r)=0   $$
Is there any error?. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Big-O denotes set of function. So how can we understand $f \sim O(g)$ ? From your attempt I see, that you want this to mean $\frac{f}{\phi}\to 1$ for $\forall \phi \in O(g)$, but this is **impossible**.

Comment: @zkutch Thanks.  How is this impossible?

Comment: Assume $\phi \in O(g)$ and $\frac{f}{\phi}\to 1$. Then for any $C>0, C \neq 1$ constant, $C\cdot\phi \in O(g)$, but $\frac{f}{C\cdot\phi}\to \frac{1}{C}\neq 1$.

Comment: @zkutch Thanks a lot. So what is the correct statement?

Comment: Can you share where did you get that definition?

Comment: @zkutch I am sorry. I am new to this asymptotics. Please help me out

Comment: Of course - formulate, please, the task you are facing and I will try to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler direct approach:
Since
$I(r)\sim 
 \mathcal{O}    \left(\log{(1-\sqrt{1-r^2})}\right)$ as $r\to 1^-$,
then there are a $\delta>0$, and a constant $C>0$ such that

$$|I(r)|\leq C\left|\log{(1-\sqrt{1-r^2})}\right|, \quad 1-\delta<r<1.$$

Since $\lim_{r\rightarrow 1^{-}}\log{(1-\sqrt{1-r^2})}=0$
then $\lim_{r\rightarrow 1^{-}}I(r)=0$.

Comment: But don't we require that for asymptotic equivalence to be well defined , $\lim_{r\to 1^-}\mathcal{O}    \left(\log{(1-\sqrt{1-r^2})}\right)\neq 0$?

Comment: If you find an answer useful, you should upvote it. It you think it is also correct then you should accept it by clicking the "accept " button.

Comment: $\lim_{r\rightarrow 1^{-}}\log{(1-\sqrt{1-r^2})}=\lim_{r\rightarrow 1^{-}}\log{(1-\sqrt{1+r}\sqrt{1-r})}=\log{(1-0)}=0$ because =$\lim_{r\rightarrow 1^{-}}\sqrt{1-r}=0$ and the logarithmic function is continuous near $1$.

Comment: Sorry, your last comment I did not understand.

Comment: Can we say from equation $(1)$ that $I(r)<0$ for all $0<r<1$. I will accept your answer. Please answer my last doubt.

Comment: I am not sure if we could say that from (I)....But do you agree with the inequality $|I(r)|\leq C\left|\log{(1-\sqrt{1-r^2})}\right|, \quad 1-\delta<r<1$ ?

Comment: Yes I agree with your last comment.

Comment: So, we are done by the squeezing theorem!

Comment: Yes but can we say something about the sign of $I(r)$?

Comment: Please reply. I will accept your answer.

Comment: I don't have 15 reputations to upvote but I will definitely accept your answer. Please reply

Comment: Please tell me about the sign of $I(r)$.

Comment: How did you get that : Since 
$I(r)\sim 
 \mathcal{O}    \left(\log{(1-\sqrt{1-r^2})}\right)$ as $r\to 1^-$,
then there are a $\delta>0$, and a constant $C>0$ such that 

$$|I(r)|\leq C\left|\log{(1-\sqrt{1-r^2})}\right|, \quad 1-\delta<r<1.$$?

Comment: The big O notation definiton implies the above. But how does "$\sim$" notation imply the above statement?

Comment: +1 for concise answer.

Comment: @Harry No, we can't say much about the sign of $I(r)$. How did we get from $\sim$ to the inequality: well, the inequality holds only in a small left neighborhood  of $1$. The way I understand it is as we get close enough to $1$ from the left, $I(r)$ behaves like something bounded (up to a constant multiple) by the logarithm ...